# low memory consuming JAVA ide for MAC OSX?

Tags: eclipse, macos, memory, netbeans, intellij-idea

I have been using MAC OSX and since beginning I have had problems with memory consumption of JAVA ides.. I have tried Netbeans, Eclipse and Intellij, tried to configure jvm settings especially for eclipse but memory problem remains...

basically, although i am not doing any compiling or building, keeping one single project open makes my ide to consume more than 750 mb of ram.. this is same for all the ides i wrote above and customizations of ini files makes a little impact...

are there any low memory consuming ides around? or something written for mac only so probably it will handle ram issues in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart IDE needs to index all your project and SDK files to provide code completion and other intelligent features. The index needs to be stored somewhere, so there would be always a tradeoff between intelligence, performance and memory consumption.

If IDE chooses to minimize the memory usage, it will have to store cache on disk and load it when you invoke some feature that requires some data from the cache, you'll get a delay when using a feature, which is unacceptable and will slow down editing.

Of course you want your IDE to be fast. To achieve this, it needs to always have most of the caches and indexes already loaded in memory, but you'll see higher memory usage.

Whether you like it or not, but most modern applications prefer to be faster and consume more RAM, rather than to be slow and consume less RAM. Chrome browser with 5 open tabs will consume more memory than your IDE.

Memory is a cheap resource (unless you have old hardware that you can't upgrade by installing more RAM, like a laptop). Normally developers do not save on hardware. In order to be productive when using IDEs they have systems with at least 8GB of RAM. Developers working with Java and application servers can have even more. The price of 24GB is ~$100-150 now.

Would you save on RAM and then look for a slow or feature limited IDE that can work on your system? Or would you buy better hardware and forget about this resource for several years while enjoying the IDE providing more features and speed?

Comment: thank you so much for the explanatory response @CrazyCoder, i am aware of all these as a developer but on the other hand it is more than annoying to see your ram is being consumed by an idle IDE  - as you may guess i run many apps at the same time. the reason i post this here i dont want to upgrade the ram (main board doesnt let me use more than 4 gb so even if i wanna, i cant) a low weight ide with less features would help a lot

Comment: Can't tell for all the IDEs, but in IntelliJ IDEA you can disable plug-ins that you don't need, disable inspections and intentions, or even enable **Power Save Mode** that turns off code analysis. Runnin in 32-bit mode will also reduce memory usage: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1232. Maximum memory can be limited: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-197. If it's still uses too much for your config, I doubt that you'll find a Java IDE with less memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off with a text editor like http://www.sublimetext.com/

Or if you want to be old school, vi or emacs.

You can reduce Eclipse's memory usage if you tweak settings and remove things you don't need.  In particular, don't run the EE version, disable spell checking, and keep your project workspace tidy (1 project).

Comment: i have done disabled many stuff and changed settings on eclipse already but still it is consuming too high..
i prefer an ide rather than a text editor, i have textmate but i am curious if there are any ides around, the project is some kinda big and dealing with editors are usually too tiring in this case